# can we enqueue and dequeue at the same time

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I am learning about queue. I have question: can we use queue like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJwr4.png) and should we use queue like that. Please explain carefully because i am newbie in data structures and algorithms. thanks for your help.

Comment: You aren't really asking the question you think you are asking.  What kind of difference do you imagine there is between "enqueue and dequeue at the same time" and "enqueue and then dequeue"?

Comment: “enqueue and dequeue at the same time”: I mean after I dequeue one value then move all values left one step then enqueue another value to the queue

Comment: I watched the visualize video about queue and I saw: they dequeue all value from the queue then they enqueue again

Comment: First-in-first-out behavior means that things come out in the same order that they went in.   That is  part of the *definition* of a queue, so yes those kinds of operations are what a queue is for.  The notion that there are two "ends", or that things "move" inside to the left or right is just a mental picture of how it works.  It lets you think correctly about how to use a queue, but doesn't accurately reflect what happens inside.

Comment: Rather than moving things whenever you dequeue an item, consider implementing a [circular queue](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/circular-queue-set-1-introduction-array-implementation/)

Comment: that is what I am looking for. tks for that @JimMischel